# usbcore kernel module on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, kernel

I need the usbcore kernel module to connect a digital oszilloscope to the usb port. (http://www.bitscope.com/)

How can I install the usbcore kernel module?

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop.

```
lsmod |grep usb

usbnet                 45056  3 rndis_host,rndis_wlan,cdc_ether
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
usb_storage            69632  1 uas
btusb                  40960  0 
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  3 usbhid,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
```

Help is greatly appreciated. (Tried the manufacturer first but without success so far. :-( )

Comment: Tell us more about your problems. I do not think it is missing usbcore module that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your reference materials are a little out of date.
What used to be called the usbcore module is now builtin.
You can check by attempting to remove it:

```
$ sudo modprobe -v -r usbcore
modprobe: FATAL: Module usbcore is builtin.
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, this info helped me to move on and find the cause of the problem elsewhere. (My user account needed to be part of the `dialout` group.) It makes sense to me that the `usbcore` module is now built into the kernel.